# Scala slick: Query field name configurable

Tags: java, scala, slick

I am a little confused in how to do this(I am simplifying the example):

```
var b = "first_name"
    val f: Future[Unit] = {
    val myquery: DBIO[Seq[(Int, String, String)]] = participants.result
    val queryResults = db.run(myquery)
    queryResults.map {
      _.foreach {
        case (first_name, last_name, address) => println(b)//HERE IS MY PROBLEM
      }
    }
  }
```

So what this is doing, it is printing:

```
 first_name
```

but what I actually want is the results of my query inside the column first_name.

Why am I doing this? I want to access columns then do my computations given the selected columns by a config file.

Thanks in advance

Tona

Comment: what version of slick you're using? where do you define `allQuery` ?

Comment: oh my bad, it should be myquery.  I am using 3.0

Comment: that was the problem? allQuery was wrong?

Comment: No, I am looking to get is the value of the first_name variable instead of getting a string called "first_name"

Comment: I defined for myself:                                                                                             val a :Seq[(Int, String, String)] = Seq((1,"a","a"),(2,"b","b"))                             then:          Await.result(Future(a).map{ _.foreach{ case (first_name, last_name, address) => print(first_name)}}, 10 seconds) . And I get 1 2 as an output. What is the type you get of "_" in foreach statement?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. The problem is in that I am not sure what fields I am going to get since it has to be configurable. 
userA: just wants first_name
userB: wants first_name, last_name and address. 

Therefore, I want to do my query in a way that it changes depending in the user selection. What I currently did is just get the whole table then parse dependin in the user selection, but I think  a better solution would be make the query dynamic.